# Dynamically loading UserControl after clicking button on another UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with displaying UserControl on my Form.

The program in the nutshell:

1. In Form1 I have a button. After clicking this, in the Panel (container) my first UserControl (new.cs) are dynamically loaded.
2. On that panel I have another button that leads to another UserControl (choice.cs) and I want to display it in the same Panel (container) on my Form1.

The first point works good, but I have a problem with second one. I think I have to correct choice_button_Click function. Is there an easy way to do it?

Here is my code:

Form1.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void new_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!container.Controls.Contains(@new.Instance))
            {
                container.Controls.Add(@new.Instance);
                @new.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                @new.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                @new.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
        }

        public Panel getContainer()
        {
            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

new.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class @new : UserControl
    {
        private static @new _instance;
        public static @new Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new @new();
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public @new()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void choice_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Form1 main = new Form1())
            {
                if (!main.getContainer().Controls.Contains(choice.Instance))
                {
                    main.getContainer().Controls.Add(choice.Instance);
                    choice.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    choice.Instance.BringToFront();
                }
                else
                {
                    choice.Instance.BringToFront();
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

choice.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class choice : UserControl
    {
        private static choice _instance;
        public static choice Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new choice();
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public choice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functional problem is that you aren't placing `choice.Instance` inside your instance of your `Form1`.  You are creating a new form instead, placing it there, then discarding that form.

However, you also have an issue in your design, where you are violating the principal wherein a `UserControl` shouldn't be directly accessing and modifying its parent form.  You would be better off adding an event to `@new`, raising that event from the button click, then handling that event in your form instance.

For example:

new.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class @new : UserControl
    {
        private static @new _instance;
        public static @new Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new @new();
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler StepCompleted;

        public @new()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void choice_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StepCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And Form1.cs:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void new_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!container.Controls.Contains(@new.Instance))
            {
                container.Controls.Add(@new.Instance);
                @new.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                @new.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                @new.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
        }

        private void new_StepCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!container.Controls.Contains(choice.Instance))
            {
                container.Controls.Add(choice.Instance);
                choice.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                choice.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                choice.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you're obviously going to be working on the same form instance, since it itself is the one handling the event.  Also, `@new` doesn't need to do any awkward lookup to find the proper `Form1` instance and modify the form.