# How do I display another UserControl by Clicking on button in One UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, user-controls

I'm very new to coding and at this moment I've started a personal project with Windows Form Application.

I have a form with a few buttons and a panel as a container. The buttons load the usercontrol as expected with the help of this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ63E_9ASwM

But, in One of the usercontrol I've got 2 buttons. That I want to load usercontrols for each button. I have no idea how to go about to make this work. I have tried using the same method for this as the above without succes.

I found another Question that is asking the exact same thing, but it doesn't make any sense to me. [Dynamically loading UserControl after clicking button on another UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143217/dynamically-loading-usercontrol-after-clicking-button-on-another-usercontrol)

I have a concern about the 2 buttons in the usercontrol. If a usercontrol is loaded in to the panelcontainer, will the buttons then disappear

Can someone explains this or is there a easier way to make this work?

This is the button that loads a Usercontrol with 2 buttons in form1(cs).

```
private void Personbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelSelection.Height = Personbutton.Height;
    panelSelection.Top = Personbutton.Top;

    if (!ContainerPanel.Controls.Contains(ucPerson.Instance))
    {
        ContainerPanel.Controls.Add(ucPerson.Instance);
        ucPerson.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ucPerson.Instance.BringToFront();
    }
    else
        ucPerson.Instance.BringToFront();
}
```

This is the usercontrol that loads in to the container.

```
private static ucPerson _instance;

public static ucPerson Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new ucPerson();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

When pressing these buttons I want to load another/new usercontrol. Without making the buttons disappear.

```
private void CPbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CPbutton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
    APbutton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
}

private void APbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    APbutton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
    CPbutton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
}
```

Comment: Soo. I have thoroughly looked at the answer and followed it and it still does nothing for me...

Is there anyone that have a solution for this??